# Meteorjs test Meteor methods

Tags: testing, meteor, mocha.js

I have the following simple Meteor Method that I want to test.
It inserts a given Object into my collection

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertHelper(profile){
      HelperCollection.insert(profile);
      return true;
   },
}
```

For Testing i use "dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
My Test so far is the following:

```
describe('methods', () => {
  it('can delete owned task', () => {
    Meteor.call('insertHelper',{a: 1});
  });
});
```

When running my tests I get the message " Error: Method 'insertHelper' not found [404]"

So how can I access my Meteor methods from my Test suite?

Comment: DId you include the method file in your test file ?

Comment: thanks! I forgot to include my methods.js file   with require('../lib/lib/methods.js');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, we have to include the files where the Meteor methods are defined in order to test them :

`import '/path/to/method/file.js';`

or with `require` :

`require('/path/to/methos/file.js');`

**EDIT**

[Meteor advises](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require) to use `import` instead of using `require`, if you can.